# Elementary questions about an equality of $\mathbf{E}[X] $

Tags: real-analysis, probability, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The following  problem comes from page 184 *Introduction to Probability 2nd edition*, by Dimitri P. Bertsekas and John N. Tsitsiklis.[image]

---

My questions:

$(1)$. When $X$ is continuous, we might have $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X>x)=+\infty $ and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X<- x)=+\infty $ ( Considering Cauchy distribution:the cumulative distribution function $F(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}(\arctan x +\frac{\pi}{2})$ ). In that case,$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X>x) - \int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X<- x)=(+\infty)-(+\infty)$ makes nonsense. Whether the equation $\mathbf{E}[X]=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X>x)-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X<- x)$  in **Problem** $3^{*}$ have already implied both $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X> x)$ and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X<- x)$ are convergence ?

$(2).$ In the solution of **Problem** $3^{*}$, why the equality 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{x}^{\infty}f_{X}(y)dy\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{y}f_{X}(y)dx\right)dy$$ holds from the views of Improper Riemann integrals ? It seems like Fubini's theorem in Riemann Integrals. Whether the Fubini's theorem  still holds in Improper Riemman integrals ? I have little knowledge about Lebesgue integrals and Lebesgue measures, but I gauss the equality maybe hold in views of Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: Your objection formulated in $(1)$ is IMV justified by the lack of further info. In $(2)$ things are okay if you read the integrals as integrals wrt Lebesgue measure. As you suggested: Fubini.

Comment: @drhab:$$\textrm{(L-integrals)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{x}^{\infty}f_{X}(y)dy\right)dx=\textrm{(Improper R- integrals)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{x}^{\infty}f_{X}(y)dy\right);$$

$$\textrm{(L-integrals)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{y}f_{X}(y)dx\right)dy= \textrm{(Improper R- integrals)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{y}f_{X}(y)dx\right)dy.$$  Are  the above equalities correct ?

Comment: Cauchy distribution has no expected value, no wonder the formula does not produce a valid expression for expected value in this case.

Comment: @kludg:If so,before applying the formula,must we ensure 
both $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X> x)$ and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X<- x)$ are convergence ? Maybe there are some cases such that $\mathbf{E}[X]$ exists but $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X> x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X<- x)=+\infty.$

Answer (score 1):

I feel it necessary to revise as "Let $X$ be a discrete or continuous random variable with the expected value  is well-defined (viz.$\int_{0}^{+\infty}|x|f_{X}(x)dx<+\infty$), show that $\mathbf{E}[X]=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X> x)-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X<- x).$ " From the revision,we ensure both $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X> x)$ and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X<- x)$ are convergence,since $\int_{0}^{+\infty}|x|f_{X}(x)dx<+\infty.$ And then,if  $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X> x)<＋\infty$,we have no difficulty to proof $\int_{0}^{＋\infty}\left(\int_{x}^{＋\infty}f_{X}(y)dy\right)dx=\int_{0}^{＋\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{y}f_{X}(y)dx\right)dy$ in the views of Improper Riemann integrals.

The final conclusion:Let $X$ be a discrete or continuous random variable. Its expected value $\mathbf{E}[X]$ is well-defined (viz.$\int_{0}^{+\infty}|x|f_{X}(x)dx<+\infty$)$\Longleftrightarrow$Both $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X> x)$ and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{P}(X<- x)$ are convergence.According to this conclusion,the Expectation of Cauchy distribution can not be well-defined.